Restriction in Fourier multiplier definition
Definition (Fourier multiplier) Let $m\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The function $m$ is called a fourier multiplier for $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if the operator $T_m(u)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(m\widehat{u}\right)$,, $u$ Schwartz function, can be extended to a bonuded operator on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
Question. If $m$ is a Fourier multiplier for $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $m$ is a Fourier multiplier for $L^p(\Omega)$? (Does the question make sense?
My attempt: If $m$ is a Fourier multiplier for $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $\left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(m\widehat{u}\right)\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq C\left\|u\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ for any $u\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Let $v=u$ on $\Omega$ and $v=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega$, then $v\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $\left\|T_m(v)\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq C\left\|v\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ is equal to  $\left\|T_m(u)\right\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C\left\|u\right\|_{L^p(\Omega)}$. Therefore, $m$ is a fourier multiplier for $L^p(\Omega)$ too. Is this correct? Thanks.
